# Stop GoToAll from searching JS files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In a SPA Visual Studio project how can I stop GoToAll (`Ctrl+T` by default) from searching Javascript/TypeScript files without ignoring them in publish?

I've tried `<None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />` in the API/SPA `.csproj` but, while it really remove `.js` files from being listed in search, this stops the publish task from compiling the SPA files(e.g. `npm run build`). I've hoped for some setting in Visual Studio options itself instead of changing project files, but couldn't find anything.

This is specially problematic when `Ctrl+T` finds something in a minified javascript file, tries to preview it and crashes the program because the file is too long.

[image: search crashing vs]

Comment: Similar problem, but not identical: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/All-in-one-Code-search-improperly-gives/10288101